# Mouse cursor has wrong postition (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: unity, 16.04, mouse, compiz, cursor

The mouse cursor in some apps (Chromium, Opera, JOSM and some others) sometimes points at the wrong position. The real point is a little bit lower than the cursor. At the same time, the cursor is working well in the dash menu, panel menus and desktop.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 x64, Unity.

[image]

Comment: Those can be website specific. Did you try same website in another OS like Windows?

Comment: It is not website. I had problem in different programs. Problem can be soloved in CCSM: 
"CompizConfig option Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher > Show live previews of windows in the Switcher. When the option is checked the mouse mismatch doesn't occur"
But "show desktop" is not working after it.